# how to add confirmation of user in authentication from mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have authentication process but it saves the user when sign up and login can be done once sign up is completed. I want to send a mail to the user to conform the account, only then he must be able to login. How can i add this feature in my existing authentication system?

Comment: I did not use any gem. I just followed this link http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch and made an authentication system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty good gem that helps you with user authentication workflows. Devise can be found here: http://rubygems.org/gems/devise

But if you want to develop your own authentication system, you need to save the user on the database, and use a column for to manage the registration state (e.g. registered / confirmed).

To send e-mails to the user, please take a look at the action mailer documentation page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: I tried devise example and i worked fine but i could not able to change the views so i tried another way from railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch which went well, but missing account confirmation from mail.

Comment: You can override the devise views. The documentation could be better in that part, but it can be done. Look at the devise source code and create the same views' structure in your app. Copy the views in the gem  to your app/views/devise/... and edit them in place. Rails will use the views you define instead of the views in the gem. Source code can be found here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I could not find where to change the views in the https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications. Please look at this example.

Comment: Right. The documentation is not the best on that part. If you look at the gem source, it has the views in there. Including the mail views. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/views/devise/mailer. Just copy the respective file to your app, overriding the full directory. For example, copy app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb from the gem to your local app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb. Then edit the file to your own needs. That should work.